# Assembly language adding two numbers code error issue

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, x86-16

I am working on the assembly language that adds two user input numbers and then returns the sum. However, my code does not work properly. Can anyone check the issue?

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

message1 db 'Enter the first number: $'
message2 db 'Enter the second number: $'
    result_message db 'The sum is: $'
    newline db 13, 10, '$'
    buffer db 6, ?, 6 dup('$')
    num1 dw ?
    num2 dw ?
    sum dw ?

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Display message to enter the first number
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, message1
    int 21h

    ; Read the first number
    mov ah, 0ah ; 
    lea dx, buffer
    int 21h
    mov si, offset buffer + 2
    mov cx, 0
    mov cl, buffer[1]
    call convert_to_number

    ; Store the first number
    mov num1, ax

    ; Display message to enter the second number
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, message2
    int 21h

    ; Read the second number
    mov ah, 0ah ; 
    lea dx, buffer
    int 21h
    mov si, offset buffer + 2
    mov cx, 0
    mov cl, buffer[1]
    call convert_to_number

    ; Store the second number
    mov num2, ax

    ; Add the numbers
    mov ax, num1
    add ax, num2
    mov sum, ax

    ; Display the result
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, result_message
    int 21h

    ; Convert sum to ASCII
    mov ax, sum
    call convert_to_ascii ; Fixed error: Corrected procedure call

    ; Display sum
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, buffer + 5 ; Fixed error: Adjusted offset
    int 21h

    ; New line
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, newline
    int 21h

    ; Exit program
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

convert_to_number:
    xor ax, ax
convert_loop:
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
    cmp bl, 0
    je convert_done
    sub bl, '0'
    mov dx, ax
    mov ax, 10
    mul dx
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    jmp convert_loop
convert_done:
    ret

convert_to_ascii:
    mov bx, 10
    mov si, offset buffer + 5
    mov byte ptr [si], '$'
convert_loop2:
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    add dl, '0'
    dec si
    mov [si], dl
    test ax, ax
    jnz convert_loop2
    ret
end main
```

I have tried some number changes, but didn't work

Comment: A [mcve] needs to describe how it didn't work, preferably with some details you see with a debugger single-stepping like which instruction first did something you didn't expect in terms of register values.

Comment: Show the unexpected output and your debugging effort. If you don't have a debugger or don't know how to use it, think about having/using it. But at least post whatever the machine threw and your guesses about what you think is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ax, sum
> call convert_to_ascii ; Fixed error: Corrected procedure call
> ; Display sum
> mov ah, 9
> lea dx, buffer + 5 ; Fixed error: Adjusted offset
> int 21h
> ```

Your *convert_to_ascii* code is correct, but it will never display anything because you have set the DX register to the end of the buffer (where the string terminator **$** was placed). Upon returning from *convert_to_ascii* the SI register is pointing at the first digit of the converted number, so what you need to do is write `mov dx, si`.

---

> ```
> convert_to_number:
>    xor ax, ax
> convert_loop:
>    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
>    cmp bl, 0
>    je convert_done
>    sub bl, '0'
>    mov dx, ax
>    mov ax, 10
>    mul dx
>    add ax, bx
>    inc si
>    jmp convert_loop
> convert_done:
>     ret
> ```

Your *convert_to_number* has multiple issues!

- When adding the current digit from BL to the current number, the addition that you use must make sure that the BH register is 0.
- The input that DOS gives you is **not zero-terminated**. The terminator that DOS uses is the carriage return, so instead of `cmp bl, 0` you need to write `cmp bl, 13`.
- You could shorten the multiplication a bit. Instead of transferring AX to DX, followed by loading AX with 10, you can load DX with 10. From `mov dx, ax` `mov ax, 10` `mul dx` to `mov dx, 10` `mul dx`.

```
convert_to_number:
    xor ax, ax
    xor bx, bx               <- bullet 1
convert_loop:
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
    cmp bl, 13               <- bullet 2
    je  convert_done
    sub bl, '0'
    mov dx, 10               <- bullet 3
    mul dx
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    jmp convert_loop
convert_done:
    ret
```

> ```
> mov cx, 0
> mov cl, buffer[1]
> call convert_to_number
> ```

Since the algorithm does not use CX, better not waste code on retrieving CX from the DOS buffer ...